# How I can use nginx as server for angular 6 application?

Tags: angular, nginx, webserver, angular-cli

I want to open the browser index.html for the application that runs under nginx and then open the application for anguar-cli (angular 6). Wherever I read it everywhere it says create the angular application and start him server. I'm lost. I think it's possible to work angular 6 using a server other than delivered in the Angular 6 box. If possible, tell me how. Please help me understand the mechanism of the Angular 6.

Comment: You should start by building the angular project (`ng build`). This will create a `dist` directory in your project. Then, copy all of the files out of the `dist` directory, and serve them using nginx (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

You used the angular-clt tag, so i think with "server delivered in the Angular 6 box" you mean the one started with `ng serve`.

`ng serve` just starts the development server with change detection and auto-rebuild for your source files und (without extra parameters) also builds a debug version of your angular appication.

To build the production files use

```
ng build --prod
```

as described in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build or https://angular.io/guide/deployment and then copy the files from dist directory to your web server.

If your application makes use of the router and you move it to a sub-directory of your server, you must take care of the correct `<base href>`